# CREATED OR MODIFY A TABLE WHICH HAVE A COMBINED PRIMARY KEY, FORM FROM 3 OF THEIR ATTRIBUTES

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to created a table, and give as a primary key, the 3 attributes, which it have.

The code is below:

```
CREATE TABLE compra 
(
    dni_cli VARCHAR2(50),
    cod_prod NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    cantidad NUMBER (10),
    CONSTRAINT pk_compra PRIMARY KEY (dni_cli, cod_prod, cantidad);
    CONSTRAINT pelicula_codigo_prod_fg FOREIGN KEY (cod_prod) REFERENCES producto(cod_prod),
    CONSTRAINT pelicula_codigo_cli_fg FOREIGN KEY (dni_cli) REFERENCES cliente(dni)
);
```

I also tried to create the table first, and then, add the constraint in order to create the combined PRIMARY KEY with the alter table, but is doesn't work.

The code is this:

```
ALTER TABLE CONSTRAINT pk_compra PRIMARY KEY (dni_cli, cod_prod, cantidad);
```

Comment: What database do you use ?

Comment: Oracle sql developer.

Comment: Change the `;` after `... PRIMARY KEY (dni_cli,cod_prod,cantidad)` to a `,`.

Comment: I try this but it's not work. I get an error which say "Specify a unique constraint name for the constraint", but I don't know the code to develope this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the primary key already exists you need to drop the key:

```
ALTER TABLE compra drop constraint pk_compra;
```

then add the key:

```
ALTER TABLE compra add constraint pk_compra primary key (city_id, buildtime, time);
```

If the primary key does not exist in the table then just use the second command line.

Also as @stickybit noted your table has an error. This is the code without an error:

```
CREATE TABLE compra (
dni_cli VARCHAR2(50),
cod_prod NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
cantidad NUMBER (10),
CONSTRAINT pk_compra PRIMARY KEY (dni_cli,cod_prod,cantidad), --<<change here
CONSTRAINT pelicula_codigo_prod_fg FOREIGN KEY (cod_prod) REFERENCES producto(cod_prod),
CONSTRAINT pelicula_codigo_cli_fg FOREIGN KEY  (dni_cli) REFERENCES cliente(dni));
```

Comment: @ManuelLucas, did this help ?

Comment: Yeeeees, it's work! thank you for the help! I have to drop the PRIMARY KEY, and then add again which "ALTER TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT"